# Is there a way to apply conditional formatting to each individual cell in excel?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Is there a way we can apply conditional formatting to individual cells within excel to ensure that if it contains data, it will be formatted?

For example, if data is added to any cell, that cell alone will be highlighted in yellow.

Comment: While downvoting, please ensure that you mention whats wrong with the question so that I can improve upon the same next time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional formatting with "No Blanks"

it will give you desired result